# Issue with image not found in bundle for app

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following images all in the Assets.xcassets as seen below in the screen shot

[image]

But it can not display the image when i reference it as suck in the view

```
Image("hTeams/\(game.homeTeam)")
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    .frame(width: 215, height: 192)
```

I am not sure why !?

Does anyone know what I need to do in order to resolve this?!

Comment: Try just `Image(game.homeTeam)`. Folders in assert have only dev structural meaning.

Comment: @Asperi i need the additional folder as I also have a folder called aTeams which holds the exact same images reflected the other way representing that they are the visitors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to figure it out myself, and its is as Prasad stated, using the Assets folder where images normally go will NOT work, when folders are in play.

You need to create your own bundle as such:

### How to create a bundle

1. Create a folder in finder
2. Add files to the folder (even subfolders if needed)
3. Rename the folder so that its extension is .bundle (e.g. "New folder" -> "BundleName.bundle")

PS: You can at any time right click the folder and hit "Show package content" in order to add, remove or modify any of the files.

### How to add the bundle to Xcode

1. Drag it into Xcode

### How to use the bundle

1. Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "BundleNameCreatedAbove.bundle"))

This way you can have as many folders and subfolders you like.

Answer (score 0):

The assets are stored and referenced using Contents.json files. They contain the image info stored like this.

```
 {
  "images" : [
    {
      "filename" : "Test.jpg",
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "scale" : "3x"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "author" : "xcode",
    "version" : 1
  }
}
```

If you see this file, even though inside some folder, doesn't have any reference to its parent directory.

So the correct and only way of accessing your asset would be to access it without referencing the container directory, like you would normally do for any other asset stored in the root directory.

```
Image("Test")
.resizable()
.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
.frame(width: 215, height: 192)
```

Comment: I agree with you, but also think its a "limitation" on apples part, for any web development that works just great, they need to allow developers to put folders and ref them as suck IMO